# Bash script "listen" to output from an infinitely looping python script

Tags: python, bash

I've written a python script to check the status of the smoke detectors in my house. it runs every second and returns a value of 0,1,2. It uses a separate function on its own thread to recognise the difference between low battery and alarm beeps.

I need a bash script to listen for these conditions and send a netcat packet to my main server if one of the conditions for an alert is met.

I tried using

```
alertvalue = `python alarm.py`
```

and running that in a while loop, this echos nothing.

I thought of redirecting the python output to a file but some reading said that it would fail if the script wrote to the file at the same time the bash script would attempt to read from it.

I'm wondering if I can send and receive netcat information directly within the python script?

Could you point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `python alarm.py | while read -r; do alertvalue="$REPLY"; ... done`?

Comment: You might not need bash or netcat. Check out python sockets.

Comment: @melpomene Just tried it. Still returning nothing. In the python script the output is produced with the print function if it helps.